# What is best way to accentuate the positive in an endorsement?

Tags: word-choice

I want to write an endorsement for someone. I have one line that begins like this:

> "I have no doubt that ..."

But I don't like the negative connotation of 'no doubt'. My best alternative of

> "I am quite certain ..."

doesn't seem to have the impact I want to communicate. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are many ways, I guess... If possible, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would use something that's a little more succinct, but not negative:

> **Without question,** *[product/service/person is great]*.

This feels less negative to me because you aren't mentioning doubt, something that you don't want in an endorsement.

Answer (score 5):

My preference: Drop the introductory phrase altogether, and simply say whatever you were going to say.

Answer (score 2):

To endorse a person effectively, whether in an advertisement or a letter of recommendation, some strategies are to:

- Describe positive traits
- Avoid mentioning negative or irrelevant traits
- Emphasize how strongly you support, recommend, or believe in the person and their ability

It's possible to do this last one powerfully by saying how little doubt you have: *I have no doubt...* or how sure you are: *I am quite certain...* (You might try removing "quite"; adding a modifier  like *quite* to *certain* sometimes doesn't help. In this case, it might make you sound less confident, because it could leave the reader with a bigger feeling of doubt about whether you're as sure as you can possibly be, compared with just *I am sure.*)

Whichever way you prefer, try looking at some examples of recommendations, where you'll find constructions like these:

> ...and I recommend her to you without reservation... ([sample recommendation letter](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/referenceletters/a/samplechar3.htm))
>
> I am confident that... (
> [sample recommendation letter](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/referenceletters/a/personalreference.htm))